# Java socket file transfer - not complete file

Tags: java, file, sockets

I have a problem with my file transfer from a server to client. The thing is that even how big the file is, the last bytes will not be transferred. Let say I want to download a file for 56kb, then I only receives 35kb for example.

I will provide you with some code snippets and maybe someone could see anything that is wrong.

Sender:

```
public void sendFile(String fileName, Socket socket) {
    try {
        try {
            File transferFile = new File(fileName);
            byte[] bytearray = new byte[(int) transferFile.length()];
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile);
            BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while (-1 != (bytesRead = bin.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length))) {
                os.write(bytearray, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            bin.close();
            os.flush();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error " + e);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error " + ex);
    }
}
```

Receiver:

```
public void downloadFile(Socket socket, String fName) {

    try {
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fName);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        int count;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while ((count = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error " + e);
    }
}
```

Any help is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this post & links in that post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251895/java-file-transfer-file-to-server/32252321#32252321 & http://www.coderanch.com/t/556838/java/java/Transferring-file-file-data-socket

Comment: Use a fixed length buffer at the sender. There is no need to relate it to the file length. 1025 as in your receiving code is quite adequate, although larger won't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while ((count = is.read(buffer)) > 0)` will break the loop if `is.read()` returns zero.

However, you should not assume that the end of the file has been reached if zero is returned, because according to the documentation, zero is a perfectly valid value to return.

You should keep reading until `-1` is returned.

Furthermore, after closing your `BufferedOutputStream bos` you should also close your `FileOutputStream fos`.

Comment: So, you keep receiving an incomplete file?  Would you like to amend your question with your new code?

Comment: What is happening now is that if 0 bytes are read in one iteration of the loop, then 0 bytes will be written in that iteration.  That's probably not the error, but it is not a very good idea, either.  Anyhow, I have amended my answer regarding the need to close the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: Generally, it is a good idea to first get things to work without buffering, and *then*, if needed, introduce a `BufferedOutputStream`.

Comment: Zero can only be returned if the buffer is zero length or a zero count is provided as the third argument. You would hardly want to spin loop in the presence of such a bug.