# File uploading and downloading with a java simple server

Tags: java

How to put a file uploading and downloading on such simple server like:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);
            System.err.println("Visit http://localhost:" + 9000);
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
                String s;
                RequestParser.clear();
                while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (s.isEmpty()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                File uploadingFile = ?????????? What is $_FILE (of php) in java??
                File downloadingFile = new File("C:\\users\\myaccount\\file.pdf");
                ////how to use the file the downloading file instead of out.write?????
                //Some files are tens of megabutes and reading line by line takes much time
                out.write("<p>Its web page..</p>");
                out.close();
                in.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for hints in such solution not a complicated tools like servlet or HttpServer.

Comment: So you want to send and receive file only from socket without http urls? You need two separate programs Client & Server. Once will send file and other will receive file

Comment: Take a look at JSch ... http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html

Comment: Have a look at this SE question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251895/java-file-transfer-file-to-server/32252321#32252321

Comment: Thank you. I also found some examples. http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0542.html

Comment: One question how to setting the header. That browser really display the pdf instead of content like:    %PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
2 0 obj
<</Length 2125/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream...?